# Why does $(13)(47)(13)(23)=(47)(23)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

Given $a=(3714)$ and $b=(123)$. Compute $a^2b$. I got $(13)(47)(13)(23)$ as my answer, but why does $(13)(47)(13)(23)=(47)(23)$? I got the left hand side of this equation, but I don't understand why the $(13)$ terms cancel out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because disjoint cycles commute, as others have already said. But to convince yourself of this, it might help to follow what happens to each of the elements $1,2,3,4,7$ as they "go through the mill". For instance, look what happens to $3$:
$$(13): 3\to 1$$
$$(47): 1\to 1$$
$$(13): 1\to 3$$
$$(23): 3\to 2$$
So $3$ gets mapped to $2$.

If you do this for yourself, you will find that the result is the same as $(47)(23)$.

Answer (score 6):

The key insight that you need is that disjoint cycles commute. This means that:

$$ (1 3)(4 7)(1 3)(2 3) = (1 3)(1 3)(4 7)(2 3) = (4 7)(2 3) $$

Answer (score 2):

Becouse this commutes: $(13)(47)(13)$; also if you check exactly where the elements go, you get that it is the same as the right side.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $(13)$ and $(47)$ commute, because they are disjoint.  Also, $(13)$ has order two.